# How to install mssql.dll driver in php 2.5.10 and windows server 2008 + SQLserver 2008

Tags: php, sql-server

I have configuration like this:

1. Windows Server 2008
2. PHP v 2.5.10.
3. SQL database 2008
4. Zend Framework v. 1.0.1 (2005r.)

I have download drivers to connect to MSSQL database and the connect is fine. The problem is with mssql.dll driver, because I have installed this driver and declared it in php.info but it's still not visible in php.info(). So I get the message:
"The mssql driver is not currently installed" in my application.

In windows server 2003, MSSQL 2005, PHP 2.5.10 problem doesn't exist. I don't know how to solve this problem. Any idea?

Comment: Did you really mean PHP2.5.10 **???????**

Comment: unfortunately YES :( It's a very old application

Comment: I think you are going to have to look for some VERY OLD drivers to match the VERY OLD php, if they are still accessible. Maybe search the other server maybe whoever installed them there kept a copy of the download

Comment: I have one mssql.dll and it's working on win 2003 and MSSQL 2005 but the same on win 2008 and MSSQL 2008 database doesn't work as I wrote. Version of PHP is the same 5.2.10 in both cases.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake :) I mean Versions 5.2.10 :)

Comment: FLOFL, quite a difference